# Docker compose command user selection

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a small question regarding docker-compose file

I am trying to run a command using a different user than root:

```
command: celery -b 'redis://' -A proj worker --loglevel=info
```

This will cause the celery workers to run under root

How can I select another user for the specific service?

cheers

Answer (score 5):

You can add

```
user: nobody
```

to run your command as nobody. Swap it out as needed

Comment: Hi, can you give detailed syntax?